# Is there a Linux music player which has nestable smart playlists AND syncs with Android?

Tags: linux, android, music, media-player, itunes

Background: I'm abandoning OS X for Linux and I've been totally dependent on iTunes for over a decade (since I abandoned Windows for OS X!).  My absolute *must-have* features, which iTunes and an OS-X-plus-Android app known as [iSyncr](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr-iTunes-for-Android) provide are:

- Nestable smart playlists: e.g., I can make a smart playlist (perhaps from 3 'dumb' playlists and some criteria), and then **I can make smart playlists which contain other smart playlists.** I've used this, along with song ratings, to craft my own genre-based "biased shuffle" playlists that make sure I get the most out of my music - I hear the songs I want to hear once a year about once a year, and those I want to hear once a week about once a week.
- Sync to Android devices *including play counts, last-played and last-skipped times.* My smart playlists include criteria based on play count and last-played/last-skipped times, so playing and skipping songs *on the Android device* must update this data *in the player software.* iSyncr provides that bridge for me with iTunes.

It would also be extremely nice to be able to import this data from iTunes. It'd be *really* nice if the software were cross-platform, not Linux-only, so I can avoid more painful migrations in the future.

The last time I searched for something like this was about 5 years ago and nothing even came close. Has the landscape changed, or am I gonna be running iTunes in a VM? :(

Comment: Just wanted to bump this topic. I have the same dilemma. Does anyone have any new info in the last year on this question? Just as an FYI banshee is a Linux music player that can accommodate smart playlists nested into other smart playlists, but it is lacking in other areas such as android syncing. It's also a dead project with no code updates in the past few years as far as I can see. So if anyone has any new info please share.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2016, I know of no open source program that features nested smart playlists.

MediaMonkey (MM) is the most complete solution, but alas it is Windows with no open source.  They supposedly have a [Linux version in work](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=67401). I got MM4 to run in Debian under Wine, but playback 'jitters' when transitioning between tracks.

The closest program (that works well in Linux )and has smart playlists, is Clementine. It does not have nested. Perhaps contributors could add a nested smart playlist feature. IMHO, the best nested feature is the ability to select a smart playlist as a filter within a new smart playlist. MM has this in its "Gold" version (which I have on a Windows box).